# Increments operators in if statement

Tags: c

I want to compare the adjacent characters in a string in a while loop, but the following 2 if statements give me different results.

1st: (this doesn't work)

```
if (input_str[k] == input_str[++k]) {
    count++;
}
```

e.g. when k=0 then it should be "if (input_str[0] == input_str[1])"

2nd: (this works)

```
if (input_str[k++] == input_str[k]) {
    count++;
}
```

e.g. when k=0 then it should be "if (input_str[0] == input_str[1])"

I guess the safe way will be the following code, but I still want to know why the other two if statement produce different results.

```
if (input_str[k] == input_str[k + 1]) {
    count++;
}
k++;
```

Comment: "I thought this would work but it does" is an interesting statement.. Anyway, change the title to something meaningful

Comment: You should read this: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/3425536). It should clear your confusion.

Comment: Why do you think `input_str[k] == input_str[++k]` would evaluate to `input_str[0] == input_str[1]`?

Comment: because he's a beginner.... and the language is light years away from anything that can be called intuitive.

Comment: it's nearly impossible to reason when you don't know the "basics"

Comment: @EugeneSh.: In a language with strict left-to-right evaluation, `input_str[k] == input_str[++k]` would evaluate to `input_str[0] == input_str[1]`. C is not such a language, but how does "reasoning" (as opposed to research, for example) help you deduce that fact?

Comment: I thought this was a friendly environment to ask questions, and I guess I was wrong. lol

Comment: @user903151: The problem here is that sequence point questions like this (that is, the assumption that evaluation will be left-to-right as opposed to at the whim of the compiler) show up with depressing regularity. I know it is new to you, but even a little bit of research would provide dozens of similar questions, and not just on SO.

Comment: @rici Reasoning can help to justify some "obvious" assumptions (which are not that obvious). And research can help reasoning by providing facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all of these cases:

```
input_str[k] == input_str[++k]
input_str[k++] == input_str[k]
input_str[k] == input_str[k + 1]
```

the first expression is **not** guaranteed to be evaluated before the second expression. It can also be evaluated *after* the second expression.

I.e. when `k = 0`,

- `input_str[k] == input_str[++k]` may be evaluated as `input_str[0] == input_str[1]` or `input_str[1] == input_str[1]`.
- `input_str[k++] == input_str[k]` may be evaluated as `input_str[0] == input_str[1]` or `input_str[0] == input_str[0]`.
- `input_str[k] == input_str[k + 1]` will **always** be evaluated as `input_str[0] == input_str[1]`.

So in short, you're invoking *undefined behavior* in the first two cases, and the only safe way is the one with `k + 1` and incrementing `k` afterwards.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for an explanation on why this happens.

Comment: @user903151 Great, btw edited my answer to be a little more explanatory.

Comment: It is not just the order of evaluation that matters, but also the order of mutation. IOW, `i[k++] == i[k]` could be compiled to the following partially-ordered statements: `(1)t1 = i[k]; (2)t2 = k + 1; (3)t3=i[k]; (4)result = t1 == t3; (5)k = t2;` The only constraints are that (1) and (3) occur before (4); and (1) and (2) occur before (5). Any other ordering is possible.